# How do I optimize memory usage in my insertion sort of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, c-strings

*emphasized text*The task is to write an insertion sort with string comparison function. I have done this and my code is working on the small cases. However, it fails to perform successfully in the online problem checker quitting with "Memmory Limit" verdict. What are your recommendations to optimize memory usage?

**UPD** *I have figured out that I do the wrong thing. I should sort an array of pointers to the strings rather than strings themselves to avoid copying like this:*

```
arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
```

However, due to my little knowledge of pointers I fail to understand how to do it correctly. What are your suggestions?

I have already done the following:

- use C-style strings of the fixed (255 chars) size which is given in the statement
- sort an array of pointers to these strings
- pass string to the comparison function `less` by pointer.

Here is my source code:

```
#include <cstdio>

const int kMaxStringSize = 200;

bool less(char **s1, char **s2) {
  int i = 0;
  while ((*s1)[i] == (*s2)[i]) {
    if ((*s1)[i] == '\0' || (*s2)[i] == '\0') {
      break;
    }
    i++;
  }
  if ((*s1)[i] != '\0') {
    if ((*s1)[i] < (*s2)[i]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    if ((*s2)[i] != '\0') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int n;
  std::scanf("%d\n", &n);
  char **arr;
  arr = new char*[n];
  for (int i = 0; i  < n; i++) {
    char *temp = new char[kMaxStringSize];
    fgets(temp, 256, stdin);
    arr[i] = temp;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        int j = i - 1;
        char *temp = arr[i];
        for ( ; (j >= 0) && less(&temp, &arr[j]); --j) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        }
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%s", arr[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    delete[] arr[i];
  }
  delete []arr;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post code as text, not link.

Comment: If your code is working already [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit for your question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `std::strcmp`? Its probably twice as fast as anything you can hand code.

Comment: I have to write my own function

Answer (score 0):

Each string is using the maximum space available, however maybe only needing a few characters.

```
  char temp[257] = '\0'; // bigger than given to fgets
  for (int i = 0; i  < n; i++) {
     fgets(temp, 256, stdin);
     char * t = new char[ strlen( temp ) + 1];
     strcpy( t, temp );
     arr[i] = t;
  }
```